# How to align JFoenix snackbar?

Tags: javafx

**Update: I've changed to BorderPane and tried using pane.setBottom(), but to no avail.**

I'm using the JFoenix library and was wondering how I should align the snackbar on the bottom left. Currently it is aligned at the bottom center, which is the default alignment.

MWE (Everything is in package **application**):

**Controller.java**

```
package application;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXSnackbar;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXSnackbar.SnackbarEvent;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXSnackbarLayout;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Controller {
@FXML private AnchorPane pane;
@FXML Button snackbarButton;

public void snackBarAction() {  
    JFXSnackbar snackbar = new JFXSnackbar();
    pane.setBottom(snackbar);
    snackbar.fireEvent(new SnackbarEvent(
            new JFXSnackbarLayout("Snackbar Message"),
            Duration.seconds(2), null));
}
}
```

**Main.java**

```
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene.fxml"));
            
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**scene.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane fx:id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <center>
      <Button fx:id="snackbarButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#snackBarAction" text="Button" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Expected behavior: The bottom of the BorderPane (if it contains anything) is removed and replaced with the snackbar toast.

Actual behavior: The bottom of the BorderPane is indeed removed (I tried adding a button and it was removed when the snackbarButton was pressed as expected), but the snackbar shows up at the bottom left. *No matter where I set it* the snackbar message will always appear near the top left.

Comment: That answer is a very bad idea. You need to take the time to learn how the Parent nodes work. If you are going to add more nodes, things will get complicated if you don't use the Parent nodes like they are designed to be used. Using AnchorPane as the root node looks like a bad idea here. I would recommend you start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm).

Comment: nothing special to controls from jfoenix - no way around learning all about layouts as already suggested by @Sedrick

Answer (score -1):

You can move the snackbar with setTranslateX() and setTranslateY(). However you do not know the width of your Snackbar before it is drawn on the screen. Therefore you have to bind the translateXProperty to the SnackbarLayout widthProperty and the Anchorpane widthproperty like shown below.

```
JFXSnackbar snackbar = new JFXSnackbar(pane);
JFXSnackbarLayout snackbarLayout = new JFXSnackbarLayout("Snackbar Message");
snackbar.translateXProperty().bind(snackbarLayout.widthProperty().divide(2).subtract(pane.widthProperty().divide(2)));
snackbar.fireEvent(new SnackbarEvent(
    snackbarLayout,
    Duration.seconds(2), null));
```

Comment: not really ... instead, use an appropriate layout (AnchorPane rarely is)

Comment: if you want to use an AnchorPane for whatsoever reason it is the right way..